# How can i make my .deb package replace a file in the system?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

you know that you can't make a .deb package that replaces a file on the system which belong to another package, but i need to create a .deb package for the settings (gnome-settings,kde-settings, in the system disk not in the home) so i need to replace the file.

is there any way i can do that in somehow?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do know that you can make a post install script, so it may be possible to use echo to write over it in the post install script (i.e. echo "Your settings here" > /etc/file.conf) The documentation is all [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/)